# Inconsistent results when evaluating an empty array for ng-show and ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class, ng-show

I am using a controller to load an array and then showing and hiding content based on whether the array is loaded or not. However, the value of the array evaluates differently for different instances of ng-show and ng-class.

My service (where the array is updated) is:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('yeahdoneit')
.factory('Adate', function ($resource, $http, Alerts, Styling, $filter) {

return {

  Adates: null,

  getPersonAdates: function(personid, callback) {
    var self = this;
    var promise = $http.get('/api/personadates/'+ personid);

    promise.then(function(response){
        self.Adates = response.data;
        callback();
        Styling.setLoading(false);
    }).catch(function(e){
       throw e;
    }).then(function(res){
        // do more stuff
    }).catch(function(e){
        // handle errors in processing or in error.
       Alerts.setMessage(
            Alerts.getAlertTypes().alertType_Error, 
            Alerts.getAlertTitles().alertTitle_Error, 
            Alerts.getAlertMessages().alertMessage_ErrorGettingAdate, 
            false);
        callback();
       Styling.setLoading(false);
    });          
  }
}
});
```

This is the controller that calls the service to load the array:

```
angular.module('ydi')
.controller('MypeopleCtrl', function ($scope, $http, Styling, Person, Adate, Alerts, $timeout, $filter) {

$scope.Styling = Styling;
$scope.activeItem = null;
$scope.Person = Person;
$scope.Adate = Adate;

Person.getMyPersons();

$scope.loadPerson = function($event, personid) {

    Styling.setLoading(true);
    $scope.activeItem = personid;

    Adate.getPersonAdates(personid, function() {
        console.log("ADATE - Adate.Adates", Adate.Adates);
        if (Person.ThePerson === null || personid !== Person.ThePerson._id)
        {
            Person.ThePerson = $filter('filter')($scope.Person.Persons, {_id:personid})[0];
        }
    });

    console.log("MYPEEPS: Adate.Adates",Adate.Adates);
};
});
```

This is the template view that displays the code:

```
<div id="person" ng-class="{ active: Adate.Adates }" >
    <div ng-show="Adate.Adates">
        ... content here ...
    </div>
    <div ng-show="!Adate.Adates" class="rc_instruction">
      <p class="sidenotes"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-left"></i> Click on one of your people over there</p>
      <p class="sidenotes"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right"></i> Their details will appear over here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the view is displayed and the getPersonAdates runs and populates the array, if the array has content, it all works fine, but when that array is empty the following happens:

1. The ng-class on the parent div evaluates to true and sets the class to active.
2. The ng-show on the first child div evaluates to false and does not display. (it has an ng-hide attribute).
3. The ng-show on the second child div also evalutes to false and does not display! (it has an ng-hide attribute).

This is the output for those two child div tags in the element inspector in chrome, when the array is empty:

```
<div ng-show="Adate.Adates" class="ng-hide"> ... </div>     
<div ng-show="!Adate.Adates" class="rc_instruction ng-hide"> ... </div>
```

Is there any reason why they would evaluate differently? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: could you create a plunkr with reproducible issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first case `ng-class` evaluate you expression as `true` because in JavaScript Array is an instance of Object. It checks if your `Adate.Adates` exists and returns `true`

Just try:

```
if ( Adate.Adates ) {
    // this code will execute when your Adates has an empty array
}
```

You can fix it using `.length` property:

```
<div id="person" ng-class="{ active: Adate.Adates.lenght }" >
```

However `ng-show` directive uses `toBoolean` function to evaluate expression:

```
function toBoolean(value) {
  if (value && value.length !== 0) {
    var v = lowercase("" + value);
    value = !(v == 'f' || v == '0' || v == 'false' || v == 'no' || v == 'n' || v == '[]');
  } else {
    value = false;
  }
  return value;
}
```

Thats why you have a different results with `ng-show` and `ng-class`

**Update:**

This problem fixed in version 1.3, where `ng-show` should not use this function anymore:

[ngShowHide.js v.1.2.27](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.27/src/ng/directive/ngShowHide.js)

[ngShowHide.js v.1.3.x](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.x/src/ng/directive/ngShowHide.js)

Github issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3969